# iOS 6 SMS message delivery reports

Tags: ios, sms

Is there a way to enable delivery reports on the iPhone on the Vodafone network in Western Europe?
This is a feature I sorely miss on my iPhone, being able to tell whether a message is delivered. 
The functionality is available on my carrier network as I've enjoyed this functionality on my N900.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SMS delivery reports are a network feature, not a phone feature**, so theoretically you might need to contact your carrier, to get more information and to check with them. Separately from it, confirmation has to be enabled/sent by recipient, I remember my old phone had this setting set to *off*.

**iMessages**, have separate notifications and format, as they are [not real SMS, but are working between iPhones, iPads, iPods and Macs](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201287). If Wi-Fi is unavailable, iMessages will be sent over cellular data. Carrier cellular data fees might apply.

#### Activate/Enable iPhone SMS and iMessage Delivery Report

1. Tap `Settings` on the Home screen and select `Messages`.
2. Tap the `Off` button within the `iMessage` section of the Messages screen so that the button reads `On`.
3. Tap the `Off` button in the `Send Read Receipts` section so that it reads `On`.
4. Tap `Settings` to return to the Settings screen and to save your preferences.

Comment: The cellular network support is in place as my other handsets display the delivery reports. I'm guessing Apple's strategy is to focus on adding value to iMessage rather than SMS.